# What API to call to send data to a PHP file on production?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Beware, very nooby question.

I'm using Vue and I have a contact form where I want to send the data the user put to a PHP file that is going to handle the data and send an email to me.

Since Vue cannot read PHP files, in local development I'm using WAMP (a local server that can read PHP files) and I place my file inside of it (sendEmail.php)

Next, in my code I'm using Axios to send a POST request to my PHP file, to the address http://localhost:8000/folder/sendEmail.php

It works perfectly fine, I'm able to get the data and send myself an email

**BUT**: when I deploy my project on an online server, what should I do ? I can't use WAMP since the project is no longer on my machine but online so I don't have a place to put my PHP file and call it anymore, Axios won't know wtf is localhost anymore

I'm a bit lost

Comment: Both your php api and frontend vue need to be deployed to a server. Once you have that you can point your axios calls to the php api server.

Comment: @LLai Alright but in my server I already have my Vue project so where else can I deploy my php api? That's what I don't really understand. Should I, I don't know, create a sub domain only with my php api and point to it with Axios?

Comment: Because if I just put my php api in my FTP client I won't be able to point my axios calls to it (I think?) since it won't have any url. In the www of WAMP I can do http://localhost blablabla... but within the FTP client?

Comment: You could split up your api to api.yourdomain.com and your frontend to yourdomain.com and use apache (or whatever other web server you are using) to point those domains to specific files/folders. But for your specific use case I am assuming you are pushing up all of your files (js & php). You can call your php file with your given domain name. yourdomain.com/folder/sendEmail.php

Comment: Ok! I wasn't sure creating a sub domain was a good idea but know that you say it there is a lot of websites with a "api" sub domain. I'll try that.

Comment: I tried to call my php file with my domain (folder in the root of my Vue project), axios says _"XHR finished loading: POST "https://mydomainname.fr/folder/sendEmail.php"._ but I don't receive any email :(

Comment: This could be a multitude of things. I would recommend tracing through your api to make sure each piece is working. For example, did my api return what I expected, if no are there any errors? Is there anything in logs that point to the issue? If it did return what I expected, what is the next point of failure? The email service/library? Did that work how it was intended.... etc.

Comment: I found the problem, that's because since I have a single page application I told my server to redirect every url to index.html (like the Vue documentation says). I removed the .htaccess to undo that (just to test) and know axios gives me an error 404. It cannot find https://mydomainname/folder/sendEmail.php although the folder is in the root of my project and my axios request is _.post("/folder/sendEmail.php", ...)_. But anyway, even if I can get it working, I don't want to abandon history mode...

Comment: @LLai Ok so I created a subdomain called api.mydomain.fr, put my PHP file in there and now my axios requests work and I get the emails with the data. Might be a bit overkill but whatever. Thanks for the help.